# Backbone validation of complex object property (momentjs)

Tags: validation, backbone.js, momentjs

I'm using a momentjs object in my model:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        iamString: "hello",
        iamDate: moment()
    },

    validation: {
        iamString: {
            required: true,
            fn: function (value, attr, computedState) {
                alert('Validation of iamString get called!');
            }
        },
        iamDate: {
            required: true,
            fn: function (value, attr, computedState) {
                alert('Validation of iamDate get called!');
            }
        }
    },

    print: function () {
        return this.get('iamString') + ' ' + this.get('iamDate').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    }
});
```

If I update the model, the `iamString` validation is getting called, but the `iamDate` validation is never getting called.

Here is [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/_ie_/gxqc3f43/1/). How can I make the `iamDate` validation possible?

Answer (score 0):

If You call moment() function, you must add the format.

```
$('#validate').click(function () {
        mymodel.set({
            iamString: 'bye bye',
            iamDate: moment('2014-05-05 12:12:12').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
        }, {
            validate: true
        });
        alert(mymodel.print());
    });
```

Comment: Why should I? I want to have moment object in my model, not its string representation.

Comment: I see.
Will be the "iamDate" an object. I think the Backbone.Validation don't support this. You must be write own validate function..